# how to get id of siblings in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
Hi can you please tell me how to get all id's in array of siblings. I got the length of sibling. Now How to get id's of that in an array .
.

In a pic if user have 3 children. If it is click "First level" it show "3",If user click `menu_tc_1` it show `0`.. or same in `menu_tc_2`, `menu_tc_3`.
how to get ids of sibling in an array. I try this but not get id's

```
$(document).on('click'," ul li > a",function(e){
     //alert($(this).siblings().length);

    //first method..
    console.log($(this).siblings().length);
     /*var id=$(this).parent().attr("id") || $(this).parents("ul").attr("id");
    console.log(id);*/

     var selEl = [];
   $(this).siblings().each(function (idx, el) {
       selEl.push('#' + el.id);
   });
    console.log(selEl)

   // alert(id);
  //  getViewFromPanel();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var arr=$(this).siblings().map(function () {
    return '#' + this.id;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/9H4e3/1/)

**Updated** according to your scenario there are no `siblings of a` try this,

```
var selEl = [];
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function (idx, el) {
// -----^ using closest and find, as there are no siblings of a
 selEl.push('#' + el.id);
});
console.log(selEl);
```

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/PZR7N/15/)**

Also if you want to use `siblings` then use click event on li not on anchor tag like,

```
$(document).on('click', " ul li", function (e) {
    // use click event on li not on anchor tag

    //alert($(this).siblings().length);

    ......
    var selEl = [];
    $(this).siblings().each(function (idx, el) {
        selEl.push('#' + el.id);
    });
    console.log(selEl);
    .....
});
```

[Li sibling demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/PZR7N/16/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `.attr()`

```
   var id=0;
   $(this).siblings().each(function (idx, el) {
       id=el.attr('id');
       selEl.push('#' + id);
   });
```

Comment: press add button and open left panel and click + button i need on that click

Comment: It works just fine. The link you sent does not have the code I suggested. Try now http://jsfiddle.net/PZR7N/14/

Comment: it is giving ID  #  and #

Comment: id's is menu_tc_1 , menu_tc_2.Please check id's of sibling while inspect

Comment: Then you are calling this loop on a wrong element. Call that on your `li` and not on that link itself

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and the id property

```
var selEl = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function (idx, el) {
    return this.id
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P2Dcj/)

Comment: @user3530755 the html in your fiddle is not complete

Comment: you need to press add button three time

Comment: @user3530755 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P2Dcj/1/ - you need to target the parent's siblings because `this` points to the `a` element which does not have any siblings

Comment: if you inspect ID'd are menu_tc_1, menu_tc_2 I need that one on array

Comment: First level have two children I need those ids